# open IMAP port Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, imap, windows-firewall

on my windows Server I'd like to install a imap server. Through HTTP the server is reachable, but if I try to connect using IMAP the server does not respond, instead if I disable the firewall it works fine.

The Firewall allows all outgoing connections and as I do not use ssl for this first try I opened port 143 for incoming connections. Is there something else to configure in the internal windows firewall?

Comment: Please post your rule for imap?

Comment: On the "Protocol and Port"-Tab Local Port is set to "Specific local ports" on Port 143. As Remote Port I did allow all ports. On the General Tab I set allow Connection. The rest I left on default settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling the "Edge Traversal"-Option it works, but i am not aware about what it is.

**Update**

Now I think that I know what Edge Traversal  is thanks to that Question: [Windows Advanced Firewall: What does "Edge Traversal" mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/89824/windows-advanced-firewall-what-does-edge-traversal-mean).

Through that question I found also a good post on configuring the Windows Firewall: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/firewalls_and_VPN/Windows-Server-2008-Firewall-Advanced-Security-Part2.html

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your firewall profile does not match the rule/location you're in.

Windows firewall is dynamic, it knows where you are, and it knows that based on your location, it should apply a certain set of rules that are predefine or that you have defined your self.

Just try to make sure that the location you're in matches the rule you created.

For more information, read this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles.aspx

Comment: But I made sure that my rule applies on all three Profiles.

Comment: Allow me to ask, rule created on the "Inbound Rules", not outbound?

Comment: On Inbound Rules

Answer (score 0):

Allowing Edge Traversal didn't work for me when I tried to open up just port 143. Here is the Windows 7 firewall setting I had to use to allow other computers to connect to my hMailServer. Starting from a new firewall rule:

1. Rule Type: **Program**
2. Program: Set *This program path:* to **%ProgramFiles% (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\hMailServer.exe** (or browse to the location of **hMailServer.exe** for your installation)
3. Action: **Allow the connection**
4. Profile: In my case, I selected **Domain** and unchecked all others. Adjust this to your needs though I would obviously not allow **Public** unless you really, really want to open it up to everything.
5. Name: **hMailServer.exe Program Access** or whatever you want to name it.

After that, everything worked fine.